# No name 'xxx' in module 'ansible.module_utils', pylint(no-name-in-module) in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ansible, pylint

### What cause this issue

Ansible supports user-defined module_utils folder, we can add following line in `ansible.cfg`:

```
module_utils   = /xxx/lib/module_utils
```

Then, when the playbook running, ansible will combine both `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ansible/module_utils` and `/xxx/lib/module_utils` together.

So, we can import module utilities in user-defined ansible module, like:

```py
import ansible.module_utils.my_utils
```

**But, pylint doesn't read the `ansibe.cfg` file and combine the user-defined utility folder with system one.** So, it can't find `my_utils` in `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ansible/module_utils`, and cause this issue.

### My question

Is there any way to make the pylint 'see' the modules in user-defined folder?

BTW, add additional search path in pylint configuration like below won't fix this issue.

```
init-hook='import sys; sys.path.append("/xxx/lib/module_utils")'
```

because in ansible module, we used `ansible.module_utils` namespace

```py
import ansible.module_utils.my_utils
```

not

```py
import my_utils
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some minutes and read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you will be much more likely to get a usable answer!